# Is it possible to use Java webstart execute .exe or dll?

Tags: java, windows, dll, java-web-start

I know java webstart is running under a secure sandbox. Is it possible to include a .dll/.exe in the jar (or have the webstart download it to the local machine) and then execute it (using Runtime.exec or process,etc)

Please Advise. Any suggestion/comment is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You have to wrap the `.dll` in a `.jar` file, and reference it in your `.jnlp` file using `<nativelib>`

See [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t126704-java-webstart-and-jni.html) for a more detailed description.

If you want to run an executable, then your best bet is to package it up in your `.jar` as a resource, explode it to (say) a temporary directory, and then run it using the normal Process/Runtime mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the user grants your application privileges (via the dialog that pops up), then Java webstart will have access to the file-system, and will have permission to use Runtime.exec.