# Invoking exe from webstart

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

My requirement is to invoke an exe file from JNLP hosted on web server.
I tried to embed the exe in a class file and invoked it with ProcessBuilder.
But it didn't work.
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Are you mean invoke the exe at client side or server side? How you invoke using Process Builder? What you mean did't work. Please show some code how you do it and is there any error, exception?

Comment: I added the code to invoke exe from a class file and jar-ed the class and exe and used nativelib tag to embed it in JNLP file.
I tried to invoke the class that contains the exe invocation code from application-desc tag but it is unable to recognize the exe at all

Comment: Have you grant the permission? Maybe this [It is possible to run exe or dll using webstart] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831050/is-it-possible-to-use-java-webstart-execute-exe-or-dll) will help you.